# How to debug a Custom Property Editor in Delphi 6 (Pro)?

Tags: delphi, debugging, delphi-6, property-editor

How can I set breakpoints and trace through a Custom Property Editor I wrote for one of my VCL derived components (Component Palette member)?  The problem of course is that I want to debug code that is running in a compiled BPL while the IDE is active and is not running an active application.  Setting breakpoints in the BPL source file does not do anything.

Links to a tutorial or article on debugging Custom Property Editors would be great too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell the IDE to use itself as the host application and hit the "Run" button. It'll spawn a new instance of the IDE, and you can do whatever you need to make it hit the breakpoint you set and you can debug it as you normally would.

I'm not 100% sure where it is in D6, but in D2010, it's set under Run > Parameters... I think it's the same for D6, but like I said, I'm not sure. If you don't see that particular menu item, you should have something similar.

Answer (score 0):

using OutputDebugString can helps ...not so cool as breakpoints and step by step  , sure , but you can trace the flow and output value